# Full screen background image minus flexible top-nav bar

Tags: javascript, css, responsive

This is my first post here and I haven't been able to find the answer to my question.

I am building a page and I want a picture to fill the entire screen, from the bottom of the top-nav bar (menu etc..) to the bottom of the screen. Only issue I have... the bar is responsive : it's taller on very large screen and much smaller on mobiles, which of course impacts my background image differently on different screens.

Here's my css :

```
.backgroundimage{ 
    background-image: url(https://file...);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
    }

</style>
```

So I've tried multiples things for hours, playing around with the "vh" property.
For example :

```
min-height:calc(100vh - 17vh)
```

That gives decent result on my laptop, but not on a larger screen. So I've been trying to find the fonction or class that represents the navHeight, but I can't find a proper way to do it and nothing is working so far. I've tried stuff like :

```
 min-height:calc(100vh - $headerHeight)
```

And so on... This is a shopify store and I have no knowledge in js, which may explain why I'm struggling. Here's some js code that revolves around the header, but nowhere can I find a way to remove the height of the header. Any idea or direction to give me ? Thanks.

JS code (not in proper order):

```
theme.headerNav = (function() {
  var selectors = {
    siteNav: '#SiteNav',
    siteNavCompressed: '#SiteNavCompressed',
    siteNavParent: '#SiteNavParent',
    siteNavItem: '.site-nav__item',
    stickyNavWrapper: '#StickNavWrapper',
    stickyNav: '#StickyNav'
  };

function init() {
    sizeNav();
    initMegaNavs();
    initHeaderSearch();
    $(window).on('resize.headernav', $.debounce(250, sizeNav));
  }

window.Meganav = (function() {
  var Meganav = function(options) {
    this.cache = {
      $document: $(document),
      $page: $('.page-element')
    };

    var defaults = {
      $meganavs: $('.meganav'),
      $megaNav: $('.meganav__nav'),
      $meganavToggle: $('.meganav-toggle'),
      $meganavDropdownContainers: $('.site-nav__dropdown-container'),
      $meganavToggleThirdLevel: $('.meganav__link-toggle'),
      $meganavLinkSecondLevel: $('.meganav__link--second-level'),
      $meganavLinkThirdLevel: $('.meganav__link--third-level'),
      $meganavDropdownThirdLevel: $('.site-nav__dropdown--third-level'),
      isOpen: false,
      preventDuplicates: false,
      closeOnPageClick: false,
      closeThirdLevelOnBlur: false,
      activeClass: 'meganav--active',
      drawerClass: 'meganav--drawer',
      meganavDropdown: '.site-nav__dropdown',
      meganavLinkClass: 'meganav__link',
      drawerToggleClass: 'drawer__nav-toggle-btn',
      drawerNavItem: '.drawer__nav-item',
      navCollectionClass: 'meganav__nav--collection',
      secondLevelClass: 'meganav__link--second-level',
      thirdLevelClass: 'meganav__link-toggle',
      thirdLevelContainerClass: 'site-nav__dropdown--third-level',
      noAnimationClass: 'meganav--no-animation'
    };

theme.HeaderSection = (function() {
  function Header() {
    theme.stickyHeader.init();
    theme.headerNav.init();
    theme.Notify = new window.Notify();
    theme.NavDrawer = new window.Drawers('NavDrawer', 'left');
    drawerSearch();
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Where exactly do you want this bar?  Do you want it at a fixed pixel position, a percentage of height position, or something else?  Also, `min-height:calc(100vh - 17vh)` doesn't make much sense, it would just always be `min-height:83vh`.

Comment: That is true it doesn't make sense as it's a responsive design (and indeed 83vh). The header is right in place. My issue is : when I use a background image at 100vh, it is filling more than the entire screen (it's going overboard exactly the height of my header, that's why I want to NOT include the height of the header to fill the screen space properly). Is it clearer ?